# Python: extract sections from a text file and write them into new separate text files

Tags: python, loops, text, filter, line

Sorry for the dummy questions here.

In python, I have a input text file as in the picture here [textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkOE5.jpg), which includes 3 sections of text, and I need to first find all the lines in the bottom of each section of the text that includes "shsux/en", and then under this section, I would like to loop back and search for all the lines that start with "udp" and "jkp", and output the whole section into a new text file.

But I'm a beginner in Python and I'm not sure what would be the best way to achieve this. Appreciate any kindly reply.

Comment: If I properly understood your intent, I would simply create a single loop over the lines and append each line to the relevant lists if any, and write those lists to the files at the end. I'm not sure why you would consider a nested loop so perhaps I don't entirely understand the desired result - if that's the case could you please elaborate?

Comment: @andersource thanks for your comment. I think what I'd like to have is to find "shsux" first (as a classifier), and perhaps use a nested loop to find "jkp" lines and "udp" lines afterwards, because the original file is actually pretty big (it may contain other lines start with "jkp" or "udp" but with other words I don't need at the end) and I only want to filter out the "jkp" and "udp" lines in between each two "shsux" lines.

Comment: updated the description of the task.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')

with open('source.txt', 'r') as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        if 'shsux' in line:
            file1.write(line)
        # Same for other files...

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
out_big = f.open(first_output_file, "w")
out_small_1 = f.open(second_output_file, "w")
out_small_2 = f.open(third_output_file, "w")
with open(source_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "shsux" in line:
            out_big.write(line)
            if line.startswith("udp"):
                out_small_1.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("jkp"):
                out_small_2.write(line)
out_big.close()
out_small_1.close()
out_small_2.close()
```

But I think the big file with "shsux" is not necessary, so you could skip it.

Sorry, made a mistake, and used endswith(), instead of startswith.

Comment: It works when returning all three lists, but what if I find 'shsux' lines first, and is that possible to go above each line between two 'shsux' lines to find the lines with 'udp' and 'jkp'? Thank you...wasn't sure if this would work.